# Change radii & speed of "rotate view"?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

When I hold <kbd>MMB</kbd>, I rotate my view around a point.  Somehow, I accidentally caused the camera to rotate around a large circle.  Then, I bound the camera to a marker, and the view jumped to the origin, and the effect was removed.

How can I increase the radius of the point around which the view rotates via MMB?  How can I **increase the speed** of view-translations (**move/rotate/dolly**)?

*2.79*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Resolution:

(1) Use "zoom" rather than "dolly".  Dollying the camera will prevent the access of rotation from shrinking as you move closer to the object.

(2) Dolly the camera away and increase the zoom to further constrict the access of rotation.

Additionally, there is a method of binding the access of rotation to a new location.  I plan to update this answer in the future to include that action.

Answer (score 2):

Click numpad dot/del to focus camera transform around selceted object origin, then zoom in /out and it'll be cool. :)

Comment: I realized that 'dolly' cause the camera to move less sharply (the rotation radius doesn't change, regardless of how near to the object you become).